# Implement Countdown watch in magento

Tags: javascript

I want to implement countdown watch which will be reset next morning at 11 am. Means in every morning at 11 am it should be reset automaticaly.

Below is the code which I implemented as hardcode, but now I want it dynamic, right now I am giving date of next day hardcode.
Can anyone please suggest how can I get dynimacaly date of next day, which should be in formate - Month(Feb) date(tommorow), year

```
<script>

// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Feb 10 2017,  12:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    //var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 12)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + " : "
    + minutes + " : " + seconds;

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is purely about Javascript. This question is more suitable in stack overflow site.

Comment: @Arohi ask this question on stackoverflow.com